# Keep application running all the time

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Basically I need my application to run from system start until system shutdown. I figured out the following approach:

1. create MyApp.exe and MyService.exe
2. MyApp should install MyService as a service
3. MyService is supposed to run at startup and periodically check if MyApp is running. If it's not than start it.

That's the code I wrote for my service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int processesCount =
            Process.GetProcessesByName(Settings.Default.MyAppName).Count() +
            Process.GetProcessesByName(Settings.Default.MyAppName + ".vshost").Count() +
            Process.GetProcessesByName(Settings.Default.MyAppUpdaterName).Count();

        if(processesCount==0)
        {
            //restore
            var p = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = Settings.Default.MyAppName, Arguments = "" } };
            p.Start();
        }
        else
        {
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

1. How can I install this process so that it starts on windows start?
2. I'm not sure if this infinite loop in OnStart method is a good idea. Is it?
3. Is the general idea ok?

Comment: Why not just have myservice.exe?

Comment: This is just hostile to the user.  And pointless, she'll of course kill your service.  Write code that is genuinely useful, the user returns the favor and keeps it running.

Comment: @HansPassant it's just the requirement my boss gave me. This app is supposed to monitor workers efficiency so I have to make it hard for them to close it or forget start it. :)

Comment: If they kill the program then their productivity is zero.  There's no real substitute for horse-sense in programming, you'll see lots of it when the users find out they are being monitored.

Comment: @HansPassant if they manually kill the program I can do nothing about that, but their manager definitely can :)

Comment: Well, you asked this question assuming that you *could* do something about it.  Yes, leave the horse-sense to that manager, I'm sure he's got plenty of it.  Don't replace him with a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the general idea ok?

As Hans points out in comments this is hostile to the user and fortunately won't work on Vista or later because services run in their own windows station.  Put whatever logic you need to run all the time in the service and use an IPC mechanism such as WCF to communicate with an (optionally) running UI.  If the user disables the service or exits the GUI respect their wishes...

> How can I install this process so that it starts on windows start?

Add an entry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`that points to your GUI application.

> I'm not sure if this infinite loop in OnStart method is a good idea.
>   Is it?

No. You need to return from `OnStart` if you need to do work after OnStart returns create a [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) to do that work.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done is have a windows service that runs the logic and main application code.  Then if you need a GUI for it, have the windows service expose a web service via WCF and create a windows app that calls to the web service.  On install, put you windows app in the windows startup.

This model will have the main application code running all the time, but the GUI is only up when a user is logged in.